# Why does the type parameter of reduceLeft contain a lower bound?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, reduce, type-parameter

The signature of `reduceLeft` on some `Seq[A]` is

```
def reduceLeft [B >: A] (f: (B, A) => B): B
```

The type of `A` is known, but the lower bound `>:` tells us that `B` can be any supertype of `A`.

Why is it like this? Why not

```
def reduceLeft (f: (A, A) => A): A
```

We already know that the head of the sequence is type `A` and so I can't think of how `B` could be anything other than equal to `A`. Can you provide an example where `B` is some super-type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your class B has a method `combine(other:B): B`. Now you call `reduceLeft((b,a) => b.combine(a))` on a list of `A`s. Since the return type of `combine` is `B` the type parameter to `reduceLeft` needs to be `B`.